# MacBook Pro crashed when inserting a USB cable connected to an Arduino Nano clone

Tags: macos, error

I plugged a USB cable (connected to an Arduino Nano clone) into my MacBook Pro (running OS X 10.11.2) and it crashed with an on screen message.

It restarted and reloaded all my apps (eventually).

It seemed to be working normally, so I tried the Arduino again, with similar results.

`Console` shows a very long list of messages. The first which seems possible is:

```
6/01/2016 11:43:39.355 AM mdworker[662]: LaunchServices: received XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INTERRUPTED trying to map database
```

Additional notes The Arduino required an additional driver which I installed a week ago (CH34X USB-SERIAL DRIVER). This seemed to be working OK.

Can anyone help with this. What can I check? (I can certainly live without the Arduino.)

Comment: On 10.7 I'm only getting crashes on random occasions. Most times it works, but then it crashes whenever it feels like it. The original nano and Funduino nano both work as expected and there are no problems with the clone on either Windows or Linux. I don't know where to start looking either.

Comment: I am facing same issue, what was your solution?

Comment: @MohsanRaza I think I found another driver, but ended up programming the Nano on a Raspberry Pi which does have a driver.

Comment: @Milliways can you share the link of that driver you found, I am facing the same issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz This was almost a year ago and a different OS, and I don't recall the URL. The driver pdf had "CH34X USB-SERIAL DRIVER INSTALLATION INSTRUCTIONS Version:V1.0" "Copyright (C) Jiangsu Qinheng Co., Ltd".

My "solution" was to use the Raspberry Pi as a programmer, but the USB chip blew up, so I used ICSP to program it

Answer (score 1):

Check the panic log in console. Every kernel panic is logged and you should be able to find it via search box.  I bet the serial driver is causing the panic. Maybe this [tweet](https://twitter.com/OSXPL2303/statuses/637141864207003649) is of any help.

I use a serial usb adapter as well for my Beaglebone Black. I did not install a serial driver on OS X but instead am running a debian vm for communication with the beaglebone black. Debian/Ubuntu or whatever linux distribution are shipping with serial usb driver, so there is no need to install extra software.